# Backbone tries to destroy collection when destroying model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, polymorphism, marionette

I'm new to Backbone so the answer to this is probably easy.

I have a collection that is made up of polymorphic models, so when I fetch I run the data through a constructor to instantiate the right model type:

```
    Entities.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'feed',
    model: function(data) {
        if (data.created_at != undefined) {
            if (data.plantType != undefined) {
                if (data.quantity != undefined) {
                    //it's a want
                    console.log('its a want jim');
                    return new Entities.Want(data);
                } else {
                    //it's a plant
                    console.log('its a plant jim');
                    return new Entities.Plant(data);
                }
            } else {
                //it's an offer
                console.log('its an offer jim');
                return new Entities.Offer(data);
            }
        } else {
            //default type to prevent uncaught error
            return new Entities.Post(data);
        }
    }
```

That works fine and everyone's happy. Until I try to delete a model from its view:

```
        deletePlant: function(e) {
            console.log('delete clicked');
            this.model.destroy({success: function(model, response){
                console.log('plant delete success');
            }, 
            error: function(model,response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            dataType: 'text/html'});
        App.trigger('posts:list');
    }
```

This does delete the model from the server and removes it from the collection, however after the model is deleted from 'model/[:id]', backbone sends 'DELETE /feed' which makes no sense. Server returns 404 because there is no DELETE route for /feed. Why is it sending a delete to the collection url when I destroy a model belonging to that collection?

Thanks.

Edit: Here's the code for the model that's giving me the problem.

```
App.module('Entities', function(Entities, App) {

    Entities.Plant = Backbone.Model.extend( {
        urlRoot: '/plants'
    });

    Entities.Plants = Backbone.Collection.extend( {
      url: 'plants',
          model: Entities.Plant,
        comparator: 'created_at'
    });
});
```

Comment: collection allows only fetch operation on it, there is no way the collection sends that delete request i doubt that request is sent by model, can you post the code of model

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: So is it doing this because the model is first using the collection url to build its DELETE request?  If so, that seems to imply I have a bad design choice here.